# How to have all the contain matches of a string column?

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, contains

Let's take this small dataframe :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Name=['abc','abcd','bc']))
   Name
0   abc
1  abcd
2    bc
```

I would like to create a new dataframe :
- Having its index and column names equal to the values of column Name
- Whose values are equal to true or false if the index belongs to the column name

Expected output :

```
      abc   abcd  bc
abc   True  True  False
abcd  False True  False
bc    True  True  True
```

How please could I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) in list comprehension, create masks and join together by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), then set index, transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html) and last remove index and columns names by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
s = df['Name']
L = [s.str.contains(x) for x in s]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1, keys=s).set_index(s).T.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
print (df)
        abc  abcd     bc
abc    True  True  False
abcd  False  True  False
bc     True  True   True
```